# Having trouble with stock prediction algorithm

Tags: python, svm, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to build a basic stock prediction tool using a tutorial. However, my code keeps hanging. Does anyone have advice?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = list(range(1,65))
prices = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename,'rU') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        csvFileReader.next()
        for row in csvFileReader:
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
        prices.reverse()
    return

def predict_prices(dates, prices, x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates, (len(dates),1))

    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear',C=1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree = 2)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
    svr_lin.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)

    plt.scatter(dates, prices, color='black',label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_rbf.predict(dates), color = 'red', label = 'RBF Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_lin.predict(dates), color = 'green', label = 'Linear 
    Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_poly.predict(dates), color = 'blue', label ='Polynomial 
    Model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0]

get_data('HistoricalQuotes.csv')
print(len(prices))
predicted_prices = predict_prices(dates, prices, 64)
```

How am I supposed to create a 2D array using a list comprised of 64 days, for the fit method in my predict_prices function?

Comment: I have some questions about your code,
1. why are you using return statement when you return nothing,
2. what is the reason to put prices as function argument when it's global variable
Can you provide more information about 'hanging', where it hangs? It can hang on plt.show() until you close plot window.

Comment: My bad that's how the instructor had it. Also, I think it hangs earlier. When I comment out lines individually in the predict_prices function, everything works until I hit 'svr_poly.fit(dates,prices).' I'm running this in Jupyter Notebooks if that makes a difference.

Comment: Probably this thread will help https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4648, in shortcut they tell to scale data before you pass to fit function.